# Entity Framework list return all properties to mapped models

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three classes: Students, Subjects and Grades.

```
public class Grades
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Student Class

```
 public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
    }
```

Subject Class

```
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return all Grades but with properties of Student and Subject expanded, like
I can access
**Grade.Name**

**Grade.Gender**

**Grade.Nationality**

**Grade.Year**

**Grade.Grade**

instead of
**Grade.Student.Name**

**Grade.Student.Gender**

**Grade.Student.Nationality**

Answer (score 1):

Use these expressions to expand your data. Note that they will not be of the Grade class but they will be anonymous class with properties you want. If you need to pass these items to other methods, you have to create explicit class that has these properties. Otherwise you may access them directly in the same method. Like, `expandedGrades.First().Name`.

```
var expandedGrades =
    DBContext.Grades.Select(grade =>
    new
    {
        Name = grade.Student.Name,
        Gender = grade.Student.Gender,
        Nationality = grade.Student.Nationality,
        Year = grade.Year,
        Grade = grade.Grade
    });
```

or

```
var expandedGrades =
                from grade in DBContext.Grades
                select new
                {
                    Name = grade.Student.Name,
                    Gender = grade.Student.Gender,
                    Nationality = grade.Student.Nationality,
                    Year = grade.Year,
                    Grade = grade.Grade
                };
```

Comment: i dont want to use like this way... Properties should be created dynamically based on the object

Comment: How does the program decide which properties to expand and what should it do with name collisions? Do you need it for any class or just for the classes your stated? In last case you may just create not mapped property in you Grade class - `public string Name { get { return Student.Name; }}`

Comment: i have declared 3 class, Student, Subject, Grade.(Grade have relation ship with subject & student)...You can able to identify relation ship with class, kindly check the post clearly...

Comment: Then what do you mean by `Properties should be created dynamically based on the object`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have proper relationships set between your Students, Subjects and Grades tables. In Entity framework you can use **.include** to get your job done.

A basic example:

```
Blog blogs = context.Blogs 
                    .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                    .ToList();
```

with this now you can use `blogs.Posts` directly.

Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: i can able to access the data, my intention is to achieve to bring property like "Grade.Gender" Instead of "grade.Student.gender"

Comment: @PrasadRaja why would you do that ? If you really want something like that, that can be done after using .Include and some LINQ.

Comment: some time list wil have master data... in that admin will define the properties, based on the i need to get the selected columns....